# Decode chars like &apos into plaintext

Tags: python, string, encoding, html-escape-characters

So, this is driving me nuts. How can I convert encoded characters like `%apos` to plaintext? Using Python 3.9.

**What I Tried:**

```py
string = 'The guy blasts the other guy on &apos;Russia&apos;s Newsroom&apos;: &apos;Totally unfit&apos; to be vice chancellor'

new_string = string.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')

print(new_string)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Unicode. It's HTML.

```
import html
print(html.unescape('&apos;'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for html.unescape()

https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape

```py
>>> html.unescape("&apos;Russia&apos;s Newsroom&apos;")
"'Russia's Newsroom'"
```